# Ionic: Android platform build errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on an ionic project for a long time now and I've faced a lot of problems. The problem I just bounced on was a new one and I really don't have an idea what to do about it.

I hope you guys could help me through this.

Build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package di
1>  rectory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Exte
1>  nsions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.0.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\
1>  bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\
1>  bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: TestProject
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Resolving module name for q => q
1>  Resolving module name for cordova-common => cordova-common
1>  Resolving module name for cordova-common => cordova-common
1>  Resolving module name for fs => fs
1>  Resolving module name for path => path
1>  Resolving module name for elementtree => elementtree
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform ins
1>  talled plugins
1>  No differences found between project and android platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Found "merges" for android platform. Copying over existing "www" files.
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "TestProject"
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "com.testProject.kandidatenapp"
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xxxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-hdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-ldpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-mdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xxxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xxxhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-ldpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\
1>  android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-mdpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\
1>  android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-hdpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\
1>  android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms
1>  \android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platform
1>  s\android\res\drawable-xxhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\ic
1>  on\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platfor
1>  ms\android\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\icon.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xxhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  land-xxxhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xxhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  port-xxxhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xxhdpi\screen.png
1>  Deleted D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\platforms\android\res\drawable-
1>  xxxhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-land-ldpi-scree
1>  n.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android
1>  \\splash\\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"an
1>  droid"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png","d
1>  ensity":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\
1>  \drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"}
1>  ,{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png","densit
1>  y":"land-xxhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\dr
1>  awable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png","density":"land-xxxhdpi","platform":"android"
1>  },{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png","density
1>  ":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawa
1>  ble-port-mdpi-screen.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":
1>  "resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png","density":"port-h
1>  dpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-port-
1>  xhdpi-screen.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"resour
1>  ces\\android\\splash\\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png","density":"port-xxhdpi
1>  ","platform":"android"},{"src":"resources\\android\\splash\\drawable-port-xxx
1>  hdpi-screen.png","density":"port-xxxhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\
1>  platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject
1>  \platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xxhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\MeesterBaa
1>  n\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\p
1>  latforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\
1>  platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject
1>  \platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xxhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\resources\android\sp
1>  lash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png to D:\workspaces\TestProject\MeesterBaa
1>  n\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png
1>  updated project successfully
1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Running command: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA
1>  \vs-npm\2.14.9\node.exe D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\hooks\after_pre
1>  pare\010_add_platform_class.js D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : net.js:635
1>  net.js:635
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  throw new TypeError('invalid data');
1>      throw new TypeError('invalid data');
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^
1>            ^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : TypeError: invalid data
1>  TypeError invalid data
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Socket.write (net.js:635:11)
1>      at Socket.write (net.js:635:11)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspaces\MeesterBa
1>an\TestProject\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js:90:22)
1>      at Object.<anonymous> (D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\hooks\after_
1>  prepare\010_add_platform_class.js:90:22)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
1>      at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:47
1>8:10)
1>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
1>      at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>      at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at node.js:814:3
1>      at node.js:814:3
1>  Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microso
1>  ft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9\node.exe D:\workspaces\TestProject\MeesterB
1>  aan\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js,D:\workspaces\TestProject\M
1>  eesterBaan
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Hook failed with error code 1: D:\worksp
1>aces\TestProject\TestProject\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
1>  Error Hook failed with error code 1: D:\workspaces\TestProject\TestProject\ho
1>  oks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am using Team Foundation Server as source control. I've checked in everything.

I really don't have a clue what is going wrong here. Hope I don't get down voted, because of the small information.

Greetings,

Giovanni

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269131/error-executing-010-add-platform-class-js-using-vs-tools-for-apache-cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to the team foundation source control. I'd to check out the index.html to make it work again. I've found the answer on [Error executing 010_add_platform_class.js using VS Tools for Apache Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269131/error-executing-010-add-platform-class-js-using-vs-tools-for-apache-cordova)

This was the solution to my problem!